# Время ожидания операции истекло в SmtpClient

Tags: c#, smtp

Отправляю сообщение так:

```
smtp_client = new SmtpClient(mail.tomvertrade.com, 465);
smtp_client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from_email_address, from_email_password);
smtp_client.EnableSsl = true;

MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
Message.From = new MailAddress(from_email_address);
Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to_email_address));
Message.Subject = "Тема сообщения";
Message.Body = "Сообщение";

smtp_client.Send(Message);
```

Пробовал со включенным/отключенным SSL, пробовал разные порты 25/26/465. Правильные настройки сейчас в коде. Но с ними получаю сообщение

> Время ожидания операции истекло.

При подключении этого ящика на телефоне с теми же параметрами, получаю сообщение, о том, что не удалось проверить сертификат. Если согласится с невалидным сертификатом, то все работает.

Comment: Проверьте, не блокирует ли файрвол. Попробуйте 587 порт. Можно еще поднять таймаут (по дефолту там 100 секунд). Также в from_email_address у вас д.б. только юзернейм (часть адреса до @).

Comment: @andreycha, Фаервола нет. На другие ящики отправляет. Проблема пока только с одним. 587 порт попробовал - то же самое. Таймаут поставил 1000 - результат тот же. А вот про адрес не понял. New MailAddress() ведь в качестве параметра принимает именно адрес, чтобы его потом распарсить.

Comment: Я имел в виду ваш логин для подключения в NetworkCredential. Получается, у вас разница между работает/неработает только в to_email_address?

Comment: Нет. Разница в from_email_address и smtp адресе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло использование порта 587. Но при этом получал ошибку при проверке сертификата. Обошел вот так:

```
smtp_client = new SmtpClient(mail.tomvertrade.com, 587);
smtp_client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from_email_address, from_email_password);
smtp_client.EnableSsl = true;

MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
Message.From = new MailAddress(from_email_address);
Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to_email_address));
Message.Subject = "Тема сообщения";
Message.Body = "Сообщение";

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

smtp_client.Send(Message);
```